# VUE WARN Maximum recursive updates exceeded in component APP

Tags: vuejs3, session-storage

i'm new to VUE js, so maybe someone can help me with this warning.
I want to save some data in sessionStorage, that after page reload everything resumes completely.
Without updated() and mounted() i'm not getting that warning. This component is directly in the APP component.

```
 <script>
import Box from './Box.vue';
import PlayStatus from './PlayStatus.vue';
import Restart from './Restart.vue';
import getWinner from '../utils/winner';

export default {
components: { Box, PlayStatus, Restart },
data() {
 return {
   player: 'X',
   squares: Array(9).fill(null),
 };
},
computed: {
 winner() {
   return getWinner(this.squares);
 },
 isDraw() {
   return this.squares.filter((square) => !square).length === 0;
 },
},
methods: {
 clickSquare(index) {
   if (this.squares[index]) {
     return;
   }
   this.squares.splice(index, 1, this.player);
   this.player = this.player === 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';
   if (this.winner || this.isDraw) {
     return;
   }
 },
 resetGame() {
   this.player = 'X';
   this.squares.fill(null);
 },
},
updated() {
   this.$session.set('board', this.squares);
   this.$session.set('player', this.player);
},
mounted() {
 this.squares = this.$session.get('board');
 this.player = this.$session.get('player');
}
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this.squares is an array. You have to stringify array or object before saving it to `sessionStorage`, since `sessionStorage` only support string type. You can try something like this:

```
this.$session.set('board', JSON.stringify(this.squares))
```

And when you retrieve `board`:

```
this.squares = JSON.parse(this.$session.get('board'))
```

Comment: The warning dissapeared when I moved session.set from updated() to clickSquare(). But your suggestion resolved other problem :) Thanks